# JavaScript Global Objects String Vs int

Tags: javascript

Please check the following code:

```js
var global_var = 1;
hello = 'hello';
global_novar = 2; 

(function () {
   global_fromfunc = 3; 
}());



var global = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);
    
console.log(global_var in global);
console.log(global_novar in global);
console.log(global_fromfunc in global);
console.log(hello in global);
```

Here only the last statement prints false on the console. However, if I assign an integer value to `hello`, then it prints true. Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: What is the result you were expecting to see?

Comment: I am also wondering if you meant to quote the parameter to the in keyword. i.e. ``'global_var' in global`` not ``global_var in global``.

Comment: Thanks. I have correct the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator returns true if the specified object contains the specified property. When you use it with an array, as you are doing here, the *indices* of the array will act as its properties.

Since `global` is an array, when using the `in` operator here, you are actually checking whether the specified *index* exists within this array. Therefore, a variable with an integer value returns true, so long as that index exists within `global`, but a variable that has a string value will return false.

To check whether a variable exists within your `global` array, you can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (introduced in ECMAScript 7). This will return `true` for all global variables:

```js
var global_var = 1;
hello = 'hello';
global_novar = 2; 

(function () {
   global_fromfunc = 3; 
}());



var global = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

console.log(global.includes('global_var'));
console.log(global.includes('hello'));
console.log(global.includes('global_novar'));    
console.log(global.includes('global_fromfunc'));
```

For more on how to find a variable in an array, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to 'Array.prototype.includes'.  Now using in, if I hello = 100, then console.log(hello in global) returns true. But, if hello = 1000, then it returns false.

Comment: That's because your array `global` doesn't have 1001 items in it, so index 1000 is not present in the array, 100 is.  `in` will return true if the index is present in the array, not if the variable `hello` is present.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array of property names. The `in` operator is interspecting the indexes of the array, not that its a `string`. Notice if I make `hello` big, enough, it returns `false`.

```js
var global_var = 1;
hello = 270000000;
global_novar = 2; 

(function () {
   global_fromfunc = 3; 
}());



var global = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);
console.log(global_var in global);
console.log(global_novar in global);
console.log(global_fromfunc in global);
console.log(hello in global);
```

Also note that `in` is not the same as an array contains.

Comment: :) ok. I didnt thought of that. Maybe browser doing something for optimization.  I will do more search on this..